# How to create multiple instances of highchart editor and how to prevent creating multiple instances in react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I will share the code then ask the question.

**First I have called the following files in my index.html of the react app:**

```
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/6.1.0/modules/annotations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="highcharts-editor.complete.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="highcharts-editor.min.css">
```

**Secondly, I have a component where I call it using the following function:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (highchartCodeOp) {
            window.highed.ready(function () {
                const chartOptions = parseHighchartOptions(highchartCodeOp);
                const newModal = window.highed.ModalEditor(modalButtonRefs.current, {
                    allowDone: true,
                    defaultChartOptions: chartOptions,
                    features: 'import export templates customize welcome done',
                    importer: {
                        options: 'plugins csv json samples',
                    },
                }, function (chart) {
                    // const html = chart.export.html(true);
                });
            });
        }

    }, [highchartCodeOp]);
```

I used useEffect because when I use a function I click twice then the modal shows up and if i close it, it displays two modals if I close both of them and open it again it displays three modals and so on. So the useEffect solved the issue.
The issue im having now the react component might have multiple highcharts and i want each highchart to have it's own editor, i dont know how to achieve that approach so each instance of the editor will belong to only one highchart editor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using it as a reusable component? Can you upload a demo in some online editor like CodeSandbox with the reproduced issue?